# Helm's kill-buffer leaves marked files open

Tags: helm

When I hit `C-x k`, a `Helm` buffer opens listing buffers that can be killed, and the mini-buffer at the bottom asks me to specify a buffer to be killed (a default is provided, in this case `*GNU Emacs*`).

[image: Helm kill-buffer]

Suppose I now mark one of the items in the kill-buffer, say `*GNU Emacs*`, by hitting `C-<space>` while standing on the corresponding line, and then move the highlight to a different line, say to `*scratch*`.

[image: Helm one like marked]

If I now hit `<return>`, what's supposed to happen? As I understand it, the file that was marked, namely `*GNU Emacs*`, should be deleted, and that is all. What actually happens is that the highlighted file, namely `*scratch*`, gets deleted, and the other two remain in tact, as shown by executing `C-x C-b`.

[image: Open buffers]

Why does Helm behave this way? And, by the way, why does the `helm-mode-kill` buffer remain open, as seen in the last screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill-buffer` kills one buffer at a time, `helm-mode` doesn't change it.

You can try `helm-buffers-list` or `helm-mini` instead, they allow you to open/kill/create/search/etc buffers easily.

Comment: Thanks. And do you know why the `helm-mode-kill` buffer remains open after the action has completed?